# Dropwizard Liquibase - databasechangelog does not exist

Tags: liquibase, dropwizard

who knows how to start migrations from scratch?

I'am running my migrations as usual, with command

```
**java -jar yourService.jar db migrate -i dev --dry-run dev**
```

But instead of running migrations - I receive

```
**Error: relation "MyScheme.databasechangelog" does not exist**
```

Who knows what can be the problem ?
Do I need to add databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock manually ?It's strange for me, because when I use liquibase separatelly from other frameworks, it generates this tables for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run my service with following command:

```
**java -jar yourService.jar db migrate -i dev dev**
```

Anyway, if someone will reach similar problem - feel free to use command above.